# Checking a number with regular expressions in Java

Tags: java, regex

I have a number `"8756342536"`. I want to check whether the number starts with `"8"`, contains 10 digits all of it is numeric, using regular expression.

What pattern would I need for this scenario in Java? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Raja D: You have asked several questions now. Please consider if some of the answers you got deserve to be accepted. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Use [String](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)'s [matches(...)](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches(java.lang.String)) method:

```
boolean b = "8756342536".matches("8\\d{9}");
```

Answer (score 4):

Use this expression:

```
^8\d{9}$
```

meaning an 8 followed by exactly 9 digits. So for example:

```
String number = ...
if (number.matches("^8\\d{9}$")) {
  // it's a number
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the number is in `String` form:

```
String number = "8756342536";
boolean match = number.matches ("^[8][0-9]{9}$");
```